# Why doesn't the code work to lock the record unless I click a few times?

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I know the record is locked [AllEntered] = true on opening the form/record, I can still do an edit/add in either the main form or the subform and only THEN the record locks. The code is in both the the On Current event of the form and the On Click event for the check box AllEntered.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.AllEntered = True Then
Me.AllowAdditions = False
Me.AllowDeletions = False
Me.AllowEdits = False
    
Me.Job_Details.Form.AllowEdits = False
Me.Job_Details.Form.AllowDeletions = False
Me.Job_Details.Form.AllowEdits = False
    
Me.subVendors.Form.AllowAdditions = False
Me.subVendors.Form.AllowDeletions = False
Me.subVendors.Form.AllowEdits = False
Else
Me.AllowAdditions = True
Me.AllowDeletions = True
Me.AllowEdits = True
    
Me.Job_Details.Form.AllowEdits = True
Me.Job_Details.Form.AllowDeletions = True
Me.Job_Details.Form.AllowEdits = True
    
Me.subVendors.Form.AllowAdditions = True
Me.subVendors.Form.AllowDeletions = True
Me.subVendors.Form.AllowEdits = True
End If
End Sub
```

I have tried various code and get the same result. I can make an edit/add on one field, and when I leave that field, then the record locks. Defeats the purpose of locking a record.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. Have you step-debugged?

Answer (score 1):

I tested code and cannot replicate your issue.

Instead of duplicating code, put locking code in a procedure that can be called from both events. Can use `If Then Else` structure or simplify with following alternative.

```
Private Sub AllEntered_Click()
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
SetForm
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
SetForm
End Sub

Sub SetForm()
Dim booLock As Boolean

With Me
booLock = .AllEntered

.AllowAdditions = Not booLock
.AllowDeletions = Not booLock
.AllowEdits = Not booLock
    
.Job_Details.Form.AllowEdits = Not booLock
.Job_Details.Form.AllowDeletions = Not booLock
.Job_Details.Form.AllowEdits = Not booLock
    
.subVendors.Form.AllowAdditions = Not booLock
.subVendors.Form.AllowDeletions = Not booLock
.subVendors.Form.AllowEdits = Not booLock
End With

End Sub
```